# How to bind data-src attribute for the image in the post using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use foresight.js for responsive image in the wordpress blog. For that I have to add data-src attribute in the place of src in the `<img>` tag.

Or I have to get the url from the image in the post and need to bind my new  tag near the old `<img>` tag and wrap that old `<img>` tag in `<noscript>` tag. I don't have any idea how to do it.

Basically it must looks like this:

```
<img data-src="http://foresightjs.appspot.com/dynamic-images/px-wright-flyer.jpg" data-aspect-ratio="auto" class="fs-img">

<noscript>
    <img src="http://foresightjs.appspot.com/dynamic-images/1024px-wright-flyer.jpg">
</noscript>`
```

Comment: So you start with the `img` element? And then have to create a new `img` (with the `data-src` attribute), and wrap the *old* `img` in a `noscript`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('img').each(
    function(i,el){
        var that = $(el);
        $('<img />').attr('data-src', el.src).insertBefore(el);
        that.wrap('<noscript />');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/46gZF/).

Or, slightly differently:

```
$('img').each(
    function(i,el){
        $(el).wrap('<noscript />').clone().insertBefore(el.parentNode).data('src', el.src).removeAttr('src');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/46gZF/2/).

Adjusted to add the `class`:

```
$('img').each(
    function(i,el){
        $(el).wrap('<noscript />').clone().insertBefore(el.parentNode).data('src', el.src).removeAttr('src').addClass('newClass');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/46gZF/3/).

But, as noted, the `noscript` is entirely unnecessary and you may as well simply adjust the image with JavaScript (since if JavaScript is disabled the image will remain unchanged):

```
$('img').each(
    function(i,el){
        $(el).attr('data-src', el.src).removeAttr('src').addClass('newClass');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/46gZF/4/).
References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: Sweet, but what's the point in adding the `<noscript>` tag with jQuery? It won't run if scripts are disabled.

Comment: That's a good point (the only reason I was adding it, to be honest, is because it was *there*, without explanation). *Sigh...* =/

Comment: Thanks David! Also I need one more thing. I have to add a class to the image which has `data-src`.

Comment: Anyway, this answer makes sense. But adding a `<noscript>` doesn't. So you could just adjust the existing `<img>` tags by adding the `data-src`.

Comment: Not using the `src` attribute is to ensure browser doesn't download images. You need to do that server-side before the page load. See here: [Img Element](https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js?utm_source=html5weekly#img-element)